Custom DNS entries based on Network
I've got a situation where I want to connect to servers using the same name but different ip addresses based on the network I'm connected to. Sometimes I'm working from home (with and without VPN), sometimes from one site, sometimes from another.
So imagine that I have a bunch of hosts like ...com, and if I'm at home and I'm on VPN, I can connect to "beta.myapp.client.com" as 192.168.10.10. If I'm at site A, it's the same. But at Site B, there's a NAT and I need to use 172.16.0.10 instead.  There's DNS name, but it's always 192.168.10.10 and I can't get the network admins at Site B to add a DNS name for the NAT'd address.
As a temporary workaround, I can alter my host file when I go to Site B, and then remove the entry when I leave, but that's annoying and it's easy to waste time failing to connect and realizing I need to update my host file.
I could:

Find a way to trigger a script when I arrive at Site B

Use that script to update my host file


Configure dnsmasq

Either figure out how to automate add/removing dnsmaq from my resolvers when I arrive/leave Site B
Or figure out a way to have dnsmasq know to give me one result at Site B but a different result elsewhere



I haven't had a lot of luck finding a product or script that will do this for me.
Any suggestions on how to do either of these, or another way to get the same result?

Use Locations in the Networking Preferences Pane

Locations was removed in Ventura, I believe?  I also don't want to change DNS servers, I want to add custom DNS entries, which I don't believe Locations supported?
